# Download pdf file via AJAX MVC on buttonclick

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf

```
function downloadpdForSalary() {
    $(".loader").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: $('#FormHeader').serialize(),
        url: "/SalarySheet/ExportSalarySheetTopdf",
        success: function (response) {
            $(".loader").hide();
            if (response.CommandStatus == "1") {
                window.location = '/Runreport/DownloadPdf?fileGuid=' + response.Width + '&filename=' + response.Height;
                showAndDismissAlert("success", "Downloaded Successfully");
            }
            else {
                showAndDismissAlert("error", response.CommandMessage);
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
        }
    });
}
```

this is controllercode

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportSalarySheetTopdf(SalarySheetModel model)
{
var res = new JsonResponse();
try
{
if (model.BranchNameStr != null)
model.BranchCode = string.Join(",", model.BranchNameStr);
model.UserCode = UserCode;
model.SessionId = SessionId;
model.MenuCode = ResourceFile.LovResource.SalarySheet;
var result = voucherSalaryBusiness.ExportSalarySheetToExcel(model);
if (result.CommandStatus == "1")
{
DataTable dt = (DataTable)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result.DataTableStr, (typeof(DataTable))));
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt);
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
TempData[handle] = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
res.Width = handle;
res.Height = "Salary Sheet.pdf";
res.PageName = "ExportToPdf";

```
            }

            res.CommandStatus = result.CommandStatus;
            res.CommandMessage = result.CommandMessage;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            res.CommandStatus = "-1";
            res.CommandStatus = ex.Message;
        }
        var jsonResult = Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
```

For Download PDf

[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult DownloadPdf(string fileGuid, string fileName)
{
if (TempData[fileGuid] != null)
{
byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];
return File(data, "application/pdf", fileName);
}
else
{
return new EmptyResult();
}
}

Comment: Please format the question properly and it seems you haven’t actually asked a question. Could you clarify?

Comment: Your poet is all code! Please add a clear question and format the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

write following method in the controller

```
    public FileResult Download(string fileName)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/"), fileName);
        //string fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + fileName;
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```